# copy text from one textbox to another based on a condition

Tags: javascript, json, textbox, conditional-statements

I am working on javascript.

Consider two textboxes tb1 and tb2 respectively

The value present in tb1 should be copied in tb2 based on a condition. If the condition is true nothing needs to be copied. If the condition is false the value in tb1 should also be initialised to tb2. Is it possible..

Comment: It's very possible...when are you making this comparison, every keystroke, on blur?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>tb1:</span>
        <input id="tb1" type="text" value="TextBox Value 1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>tb2:</span>
        <input id="tb2" type="text" value="TextBox Value 2"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="exchange()" value="Exchange">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exchange(){
            var tb1 = document.getElementById('tb1');
            var tb2 = document.getElementById('tb2');
            var condition = function(){
                return true;
            };

            if(condition()){
                var buf = tb1.value;
                tb1.value = tb2.value;
                tb2.value = buf;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that can do what you need:

```
function compareAndCopy() {
    var tb1 = document.getElementById("tb1");
    var tb2 = document.getElementById("tb2");

    if (tb1.value == "hey") {
        tb2.value = tb1.value;
    } else {
        alert("No match");
    }
}

//Add a handler
document.getElementById("tb1").onblur = compareAndCopy;
```

It is currently checking if `tb1` equals `hey` on blur.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4L5pE/

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible. You need to define when you want it to happen. onkeypress, or onblur of first text box you can call a function that validates your condition and then copies the values.

```
tb1.onblur(function(){ if(condition) tb2.value = tb1.value }
```

the code above will not work, its just a pseudo.